# Is there a way that I can add hover effect to the AJAX loaded images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a hover effect (animation) to AJAX loaded content/images? Currently I'm using this code to do it, but it only works for the images that are loaded without AJAX.

```
    $(".box img").each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 500);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Live Events*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [*Delegates*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) are the way to go:

```
$('.box').delegate('img', {
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 500);
    }
});
```

By the way, in your original code there was no need to use `each` - you could have used `$('.box img').hover(...)`

Comment: Why should I use .live() instead of .delegate(). Others saying it's the way to go.

Comment: @Matiss, My opinion, you shouldn't. Unless your particular problem cannot be addressed with `.delegate`, I strongly recommend using `.delegate` instead of `.live`. Check their documentations for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('.box').delegate('img', {
    mouseover: function (e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    },
    mouseout: function (e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: oh well, editing so many times, I ended up with pretty much the same code as genesis' :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.box').delegate('img', {
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 500);
    }
});
```

is better than live

Answer (score 0):

You'll get better performance using jQuery's `.delegate()` rather than  `.live()`.

```
$('.box').delegate('img','hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    else
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 500)
});
```